# Convert a string to a javascript code

Tags: javascript, string, canvas

I have the folowing string variable returned from a textarea : `jtext = $('#putJS').val();`

The result of this string is the following:

```
ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(172 + xoff, 29 + yoff);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(183 + xoff, 33 + yoff, 199 + xoff, 36 + yoff, 201 + xoff, 74 + yoff);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(191 + xoff, 91 + yoff, 197 + xoff, 130 + yoff, 196 + xoff, 110 + yoff);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(195 + xoff, 95 + yoff, 200 + xoff, 230 + yoff, 200 + xoff, 248 + yoff);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(200 + xoff, 256 + yoff, 85 + xoff, 251 + yoff, 70 + xoff, 251 + yoff);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(65 + xoff, 251 + yoff, 74 + xoff, 122 + yoff, 71 + xoff, 106 + yoff);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(68 + xoff, 88 + yoff, 65 + xoff, 87 + yoff, 65 + xoff, 73 + yoff);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(65 + xoff, 52 + yoff, 70 + xoff, 35 + yoff, 95 + xoff, 28 + yoff);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(99 + xoff, 37 + yoff, 130 + xoff, 72 + yoff, 171 + xoff, 29 + yoff);
    ctx.stroke();
```

The question is, how do I put this string as javascript code to design the canvas in my code javascript file?

Comment: Have you heard about `eval`?

Comment: Just put in a `<script>` tag and insert that into the document? But be careful about what code you execute there!

Comment: We have to assume here that the object referenced by `ctx` exists already within the page.

Answer (score 1):

There is an `eval` function in with you can pass any string. SImple example you can find here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval

But using eval function could be dangerous, so be careful with this.